# click more than one pixel at once in Windows

Tags: mouse-click, simulation

I want to click more than one pixel at once.
for example: if I click in an application, it simulate X pixels (from Left,Right,Up & Down) beside the current mouse position.
obviously it should avalable with a shortkey to prevent problems.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is really possible to really click multiple pixels at the same time since you can only have one pointer. If a multitouch device can be emulated there's a chance you can actually do this, but most OSes don't emulate a click if you touch the screen at multiple places. Afaik no OS supports multiple clicks at the exact same time.